# iOS - Margin Bottom en la última UITableViewCell

Tags: swift2, swift, uitableview

Estoy haciendo una app en la que una View tiene una TableView y esta, unas TableViewCells personalizadas, las cuales muestran un conjunto de datos.

En la parte inferior de la View, hay un botón superpuesto que queda por encima de la TableView y sus celdas, por lo que siempre se verá.

Mi intención es que la última celda del TableView, tenga una separación en el bottom con el fin de que esta ultima fila, se vea por encima del botón que aparece en el pié.

¿Alguna sugerencia? Gracias,

Answer (score 1):

Ya lo he resuelto, utilizando el UITableViewFooter del propio UITableView.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    var view = UIView(frame: CGRectMake((0,0, tableView.frame.size.width, 150))
    tableView.TableViewFooter = view
}
```

Así asigno una vista al footer y le asigno un ancho (150) que permite un espacio en la parte inferior

Answer (score 0):

Si quieres poner un botón debajo de la tabla, para que no interfiera el tap que hagas sobre el botón o sobre la celda que este ahí y que se vea por separado, tienes que hacer que el frame de la tabla sea mas pequeño, de forma que te quepa la tabla y el botón enla misma vista. Para esto tienes que tener un controlador que sea un ViewController y no un TableViewcontroller, ya que éste ultimo te pone la tabla que ocupa toda la vista. A la ViewController le añades el protocolo de datasource y delegate de la tabla para que se te genere. Busco un ejemplo y te lo pongo

En el .h

`@interface MiControlador: UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>
@property (strong,nonatomic) UITableView *tableView;
@property ( strong,nonatomic) UIButton *button;'`

en el .m
Aqui tienes que inicializar la tabla y el botón con el frame que quieras en el init. Acuérdate de añadir el tableView y el botón a la vista y asignar el delegado y datasource al tableView

```
-(void)viewDidLoad(){
    self.tableView.delegate = self;  //o el que tenga que ser
    self.tableView.datasource = self;  //o el que tenga que ser
    [self.view addSubview:self.tableView];
    [self.view addSubview:self.button];
 }
```

implementa también los métodos de la tabla que necesites...

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
```

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta Spidvmp, pero no quiero poner un botón debajo de la tabla, es un botón que está en la parte inferior de la MainView y siempre debe estar superpuesto a la tableView, por eso quiero que la última fila del TableView tenga un margen diferente

Comment: Entonces creo que había una cosa que era el footer de la tabla..... hay una pregunta en ingles, a ver si te sirve, si no, te intento buscar la solución:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5144835/how-to-add-a-footer-to-the-uitableview

Comment: Perdón, no me di cuenta que querías swift

Comment: No pasa nada @Spidvmp, miraré el enlace que me pasas a ver que puedo hacer. Si hay una función para acceder al footer de la tabla, miraré por ahí a ver que puedo hacer. Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Tienes dos opciones , crear un footerView o si lo que quieres es que el boton quede por encima de la tableView y no debajo de esta , pues dile a la ultima celda que va a tener un tamaño diferente al resto , para esto existe un metodo el cual puedes indicarle el tamaño de las celdas , pues ahi le dices que la ultima ocupara X y ya esta.